# Selenium Python can not find button on Page with xpath - html and example included

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I can't not make my python script click the consent cookie button on the page `https://www.topparrain.com/de/users/sign_up`

here is my code

```python
from selenium import webdriver

firefox_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor='http://localhost:4444',
    options=firefox_options
)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.topparrain.com/en/referral_codes")
driver.implicitly_wait(10000)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[contains(text(),'Consent')]").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
driver.quit()
```

I have tried `Xpath` and `waiting` but it doesn't click on it even I run the official docker selenium Firefox container

[image]

the HTML for the button is

```
<button class="fc-button fc-cta-consent fc-primary-button" role="button" aria-label="Consent" tabindex="0">
   <div class="fc-button-background"></div>
   <p class="fc-button-label">Consent</p>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the cookie consent popup accessing the url from APAC region.

However given the HTML:

[image: cookie]

To click on the element <kbd>Consent</kbd> you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.fc-button.fc-cta-consent.fc-primary-button[aria-label='Consent'] p"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='fc-button fc-cta-consent fc-primary-button' and @aria-label='Consent']//p[text()='Consent']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: thank you very much, this works. Could you explain to me what i did wrong ? i waited and i found the "p" class.

Comment: @KeschJohannsen Apprently your attempt doesn't looks wrong. However amidst a lot other things, first you need to ensure that `//p[contains(text(),'Consent')]` identifies the element uniquely.